# Why does my bash less then statement evaluate as TRUE when the numbers are equal?

Tags: bash

I have a script that I want to do something until a counter is less then the size of a line.  For some reason when the counter is the same size of the line, bash says the -lt comparison is true even though, it's not.  I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working:

```
while IFS= read -r line;
        do
                # get the size of the line
                sizeOfLine=`echo $line | awk -F"," '{print NF}'`

                #line counter
                lineCounter=0

                while [ $lineCounter -le $sizeOfLine ]
                do
                        if [ $lineCounter -lt $numHeaders ]
                        then
                                word=`echo $line | awk -v i=$((lineCounter+1)) -F, '{ print $i }'`
                                echo "<${header[$lineCounter]}> $word </${header[$lineCounter]}>" >> $outFile

                        elif  [[ "$lineCouter" -lt "$sizeOfLine" ]]
                        then    
                                word=`echo $line | awk -v i=$((lineCounter+1)) -F, '{ print $i }'`
                                echo "<${header[$numHeaders]}> $word </${header[$numHeaders]}>" >> $outFile

                        fi

                        #increase your counter
                        lineCounter=$((lineCounter+1))

                done

        done
```

When I run this against my sample file, it adds an additional line to the output because bash evaluates  "$lineCouter" -lt "$sizeOfLine" as true when lineCounter = sizeOfLine for some reason.

Comment: Why are you comparing the *line* counter to the number of *fields* in a given line? Also, this is an incredibly inefficient way to process the file.

Comment: @chepner The variables are confusingly named; `lineCounter` is actually the current field number (minus 1). Also, for Bob_From_IT: use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)! And put `set -x` before troublesome sections of code, so you can see them execute. Either of these would have made this problem easy to spot.

Comment: @chepner how would you improve it?  This scripts converts a csv file to an xml file.  Each line of the csv file contains multiple values that have to be assigned to each header.  The last header gets every value past a certain amount assigned to it.  Each line contains at least one value for each header but can contain an unknown amount of extra values for the last header (so if there are 3 headers, the lines can be at least 3 values long, but can be up to an unknown amount)

Comment: @Bob_From_IT First, can the csv contain quoted or escaped data in the fields? If it can, you need a proper csv parser, so you should immediately switch to a language that has one (Python, etc). Similarly, if the data can possibly contain characters that're special in XML, especially "<" and "&", you *must* entity-encode the strings before embedding them in XML. Those are the *necessary* improvements.

Comment: If bash is still a possibility after that, the first improvement that comes to mind is to start with `while IFS=, read -ra fields; do for fieldNum in "${!fields[@]}"; do`, and then use `"$fieldNum"` and `"${fields[fieldNum]}"` to access the field number and contents (skipping all the `$(echo $line | awk ...)` folderol). Oh, and use a single `>>"$outFile"` (note the quoting) at the end of the loop, rather than opening & closing the file for every item. Another option would be to do everything (and I mean *everything*) in `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is a typo, should be `lineCounter` instead of `lineCouter` in the last `elif`